# postgres group by error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I searched around SO and google, but could not find an answer to this one:

I am trying to run this query in postgresql:

```
select * from user_ips where IP = '%s'  group by session_cookie order by datetime
```

but I'm getting:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "user_ips.ip" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I am not very familiar with psql, I have mainly used mysql before. Why do I have to use the same column in the `group by` as in the where clause, and what does it mean to use an aggregate function?

How to get around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i dont see any need for group by clause in your query, try this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user_ips 
WHERE IP = '%s' 
ORDER BY datetime
```

GROUP BY should be used when you are trying to say grouping records by say ip addresses and you are trying to apply aggregate functions likes MIN/MAX/SUM/AVG etc.

Comment: The table has an entry for every page load. I want to get one line per session cookie. Maybe group by is not what i need?

Comment: Can you paste schema and data in it and what's the expected output?

Comment: eventually I just grouped by IP and session cookie... although that's obviously redundant. whatever